# Database schema design for a movie theater

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I have designed the following schema for a movie theater. Please provide pointers to make this schema a better one.

> movie: id, release_date, name
>
> actor: id, oscars_won, name
>
> movie_actor (link table): movie_id, actor_id
>
> screen: screen_id, total_no_of_seats
>
> showtime: id, start_time, end_time
>
> movie_screen_showtime (link table): movie_id, screen_id, showtime_id, tickets_available, price
>
> customer: id, name, payment_info_id
>
> ticket: id, customer_id, movie_id, screen_id, showtime_id, purchase_date

I want to be able to answer questions like:

1. What are all the movies being shown
2. Ticket availability for a particular movie/screen/showtime
3. Actors in a movie
4. Total sales for the day or by movie or by showtime or by screen

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

1. Track when (by date) a given movie starts a run at a theater and when it ends. This way you could ask questions like:

   - what day of the week gets the most viewers?
   - how does attendance vary with duration of run?
2. Change the ticket column to a `datetime`. This way you can ask questions like:

   - what's the correlation between DOTW, price and attendance ( ie is a matinee more effective on certain DOTW)
3. Track concessions by `datetime`. Look for correlations with what's showing and when.